# Label & enlarge endpoints of 1-dimensional CantorMesh? (11.1)

Tags: mesh, fractals

Version 11.1 introduces the function `CantorMesh`. I'm interested in using it to indicate how the classical "Cantor middle-third set" is formed.

In the following, how can one (a) increase the size of the interval (i.e., "cell") endpoints; and (b) label them with their coordinates (relative to the entire interval whose middle was omitted being of length 1)?

```
 CantorMesh[1, 1, MeshCellStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}]
```

[image: Level 1, dimension 1 Cantor mesh]

I realize that ordinary `Graphics` objects could be created to do this, but that defeats the simplicity of using the new `CantorMesh`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean like this?

```
mesh = CantorMesh[1, 1, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}];

label = Thread[MeshCells[mesh, 0] -> MeshCoordinates[mesh]];

MeshRegion[mesh, MeshCellLabel -> label, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{0, All} -> Directive[PointSize[.02], Black]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, except that I need rational coordinates for the ends. That's easy to do by wrapping `MeshCoordinates[mesh]` with `Rationalize`. But then the displayed coordinate labels are much too large, and I could not figure out how to use `Style` to change that.